# Benchmarking async await incomprehension

Tags: c#, async-await

I am doing some benchmarks using a simple C# console app written using async/await constructs of C#5 and numbers don't add up (well in fact they add up, and that's the problem ;))

I am benchmarking three different scenarios :
1) 20K calls to an SQL server Stored Procedure.
2) 20K calls to a simple HTTP server
3) Scenario 1) and 2) together

Here are more details about the scenarios :

**1) 20K calls to an SQL server Stored Procedure.**

In this scenario I call an external SQL Server stored proc 20K times. The CallSqlStoredProcedureAsync method uses ADO.NET async methods (OpenAsync, ExecuteNonQueryAsync ...). I even await Task.Yield() at the method entry to avoid any synchronous code execution before reaching asynchronous point, to avoid blocking my loop for the slightest amount of time.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

for (int i=0; i<20000; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(this.CallSqlStoredProcedureAsync());
}

Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
```

This completes in approx **10 seconds** with CPU consumption average of 70%.

**2) 20K calls to a simple HTTP server**

In this scenario I call an url on an external webserver using HttpClient and async methods as well (PostAsync).

```
for (int i=0; i<20000; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(this.SendRequestToHttpServerAsync());
}
```

This completes in approx **30 seconds** with CPU consumption average of 30%

**3) Scenario 1) and 2) together**

```
for (int i=0; i<20000; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(this.CallSqlStoredProcedureAsync());
    tasks.Add(this.SendRequestToHttpServerAsync());
}
```

This completes in approx **40 seconds** with CPU consumption average of 70% for approx 20 sec, then 30% for the remaining 20 seconds.

**Now for the Question**

I don't understand why the benchmark is taking 40 seconds for scenario #3. If execution was sequential or if my CPU (or I/O) was a 100% for scenario 1 and 2, I would say this was normal to have the timing of scenario 1 + the timing of scenario 2.

Considering I am going fully asynchronous using async/await constructs, what I was expecting for scenario #3 was for it to complete within 30 seconds ("weakest link in the chain"), being the duration of scenario #2.

There is something I don't understand here :(

Any clue?

EDIT: Per @svick request, here is the complete code of the benchmark (excluding some useless stuff)

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var bench = new Bench();         

     while (true)
     {
         string iterationsAndScenario = Console.ReadLine();
         var iterations = int.Parse(iterationsAndScenario.Split(' ')[0]);
         var scenario = int.Parse(iterationsAndScenario.Split(' ')[1]);

         var sw = new Stopwatch();
         sw.Start();
         bench.Start(iterations, scenario).Wait();
         sw.Stop();

         Console.WriteLine("Bench too {0} ms", sw.EllapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}

public class Benchmark
{
    public Task Start(int iterations, int scenario)
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        if (scenario == 1)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++)
            {
                tasks.Add(this.CallSqlStoredProcedureAsync().ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted));
            }
        }
        else if (scenario == 2)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++)
            {
                 tasks.Add(httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent("Hello")).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted));
            }
        }
        else if (scenario == 3)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++)
            {
                 tasks.Add(this.CallSqlStoredProcedureAsync().ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted));

                 tasks.Add(httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent("Hello")).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted));
            }
        }

        return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    public async Task CallSqlStoredProcedureAsync()
    {
        await Task.Yield();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_mystoreproc", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", 'A');
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", 'B');

                await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it uses threadpool, is it hitting the default limit for number of worker threads, thus becoming effectively sequential? For the two sets of tasks to run in parallel, it would need double the available threads.

Comment: Give ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads a go. could get it closer to 100% cpu

Comment: Could you post the complete code of your benchmark? Especially the two Async methods could be important.

Comment: @Weston : I can't really control the number of threads as I am using tasks/async await, so I am not explicitely creating threads, letting the thread pool manage the tuning for the threads, creating more or less based on throughput. MaxThreads would not change anything, it is already very high by default, and Threadpool alogrithm would never create that much. Anyway, it's I/O bound work so it should not involve may threads using async/await IOCP.

Comment: @Svick : I have edited my post with code, but nothing magical here..

Comment: You are timing how long it takes to synchronously add the tasks to the task list. Only time around the WhenAll.

Comment: The first thing I'd try is `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;` as the first line in `Main`.

Answer (score 0):

From the results of scenario 1 and 2, I guess queries to the DB complete faster than HTTP requests (of course, since the local disk has less latency than the Internet).
So, they would normally complete in 10s. But half of the tasks you're submitting is HTTP requests, so half of your computation power is busy with that, and the time needed for the DB doubles from 10s to 20s. During this time, the CPU usage is 0.7, which is the maximum achievable usage (so the pool is actually being effective, as it's maximizing resource utilization, even if 50% of the tasks only use 30% of the CPU).

Then, the DB requests complete, and only HTTP requests remain. While DB and HTTP were executed concurrently, only half of the resources were dedicated to HTTP, so those 20s equal 10s of uncontended execution, which leaves other 30s-10s = 20s of execution.

Even if CPU utilization is not 100%, the task manager won't create 40k threads, because that would crush the operating system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Giulio.

DB server is an external machine, not the local disk. But that's not the point anyway ;)

Considering I am using async/await constructs, I don't wait for a response from DB or HTTP before issuing next request. All 40K requests to DB/HTTP are sent almost immediately.

What do you hear by CPU usage 0.7 which is maximal achievable usage ? Shouldn't it be 1 ?

Anyway I am reading and re-reading your answer trying to clearly understand your point.

Comment: If you're making async requests, it's even easier. Basically, you quickly manage to queue all the tasks and all the requests. Achieving 100% CPU usage for some ms, then all you do is process responses, and it's the throughput of the other endpoint that determines you CPU load. And I'm afraid you don't reach 100% in the first 20s because the network is a bottleneck.